# looping thru array list

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```js
test = [
  [value1],
  [value2]
];

for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  console.log(test[i])
};
```

I tried this but it only returns `value1`. I would like to have all values returned so I can use each value.

Comment: This code seems fine. It prints all of `test`. What output are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: set value1 and value2 to something before...

Comment: Code seems fine if the values of value1 and value2 are initialized to something